# Google App Engine filter in Query similar to Like

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cursor

I have an application which requests the Google App Engine Java server
and fetch 15 records per call. I have a big database so I am using
Cursor technique to get only 15 records from database at one time.

The issue is that I have a column “Detail” on datastore which has on
average 1000 characters per record. The client end of my application
sends a keyword e.g. software, to server end and the server end has to
check if that keyword exists in “Detail” column and if it does then
return 15 records which have this keyword. How can I add this filter
in my code?

```
int pageSize = 15;
        FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(pageSize);
        String startCursor = req.getParameter("cursor");

        // If this servlet is passed a cursor parameter, let's use it
        if (startCursor != null) {
          fetchOptions.startCursor(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(startCursor));
        }

        Query q = new Query("Table").addSort("dateAdded", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
        PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

        QueryResultList<Entity> results = pq.asQueryResultList(fetchOptions);
        for (Entity entity : results) {
          entity.getProperty("dateAdded");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Search API to index your "Detail" property.

Comment: Andrei can i get any additional help?? i couldnt get it work. Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific: what you have tried, what did not work.